# Header redirect not being called

Tags: php

I am using the following code:

```
$page = $_GET['page'];

if($page == '132'){
  header("Location : new.php");
}
else {
}
```

Now, when the URL is: `index.php?page=132` I would expect the page to find the query string, see that it is `132` and redirect to the `new.php`, but it isn't doing this.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: did you try echoing something in the if clause?

Comment: Is it doing nothing or are you getting an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
header("Location : new.php");
```

to

```
header("Location: new.php");
```

Comment: Well that seems to have been my problem. Removing the space has fixed it. Cannot believe I missed that!!

Answer (score 3):

Are you *sure* that the `if` clause isn't firing? I don't see any debugging code in there.

Try:

```
header("Location: new.php");
exit();
```

I'm not sure how fussy HTTP is about that space before the colon, and you should do an `exit()` immediately thereafter to prohibit the script from continuing on after dispatching the HTTP `Location` header.

(Also, strictly speaking, you should provide a *fully qualified* URL to redirect to.)

Comment: Oh, yes. I forgot the `exit()` in my answer. *This* is the answer. And, yes, that space shouldn't be there.

Comment: @salathe: Thanks for your edit. However, I **deliberately** left the code as close to the OP's as possible, so that he can see the change that actually solves his problem. To explain how he can make his code _more correct_, I added the final paragraph. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no other script output before this point, and no characters whatsoever, including whitespace, in front of your opening `<?php` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces in your header definition:

```
header("Location:new.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your redirect like this:

```
 header("Location: new.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between `Location` and the colon, and fully qualify the new location:

`header("Location: http://www.myserver.com/new.php");`

Answer (score 0):

your if statement is not being triggered. echo $page before the if to make sure what it is that you are comparing it to.

```
$page = $_GET['page'];
echo $page;
if($page == '132'){
  header("Location : new.php");
}
else {
}
```

if that shows 132, make sure there are no spaces. anything more than that something else in your code is affecting this.